# Failed to connect to s3.amazonaws.com port 443: Connexion refused

Tags: amazon-s3, ssh, ovh

I have a problem with amazon S3, I created a site hosted on OVH, when I am on the site I can upload and download files but when I try to connect in SSH, I have the following error:

```
running : curl -v https://s3.amazonaws.com
```

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://s3.amazonaws.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 52.216.241.214...
* connect to 52.216.241.214 port 443 failed: Connexion refused
* Failed to connect to s3.amazonaws.com port 443: Connexion refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to s3.amazonaws.com port 443: Connexion refused
```

If someone has an idea where the problem may come from and how to resolve it, it would really help me

Comment: "when I am on the site" - you mean you web app running on the same server that you can't curl from? Is there any web proxy you need to route this through that's somehow missing from your SSH account that the site's service account has?

Comment: _" you mean you web app running on the same server that you can't curl from?"_ Yes.
_"Is there any web proxy you need to route this through that's somehow missing from your SSH account that the site's service account has?"_ That's my question, 
I don't know if I need something else to make the connection between AWS and OVH in SSH (it's the first time I use AWS S3)

Comment: Not at AWS end, I wouldn't have thought. That's probably a question for OVH, or something you'd find in your OVH configuration console or portal.